# Communication between two interfaces on same machine

Tags: networking, debian, iproute

How can I achieve communication between 2 clients connected to 2 interfaces. E.g. `Client A` connected to `eth0` and `Client B` connected to `wlan0`? Both will get DHCP IP.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have 2 options:

**Option 1**: Route traffic between LAN & WLAN

This keeps the existing setup you have now pretty much and just routes traffic between LAN & WLAN as required.

First, [enable IPv4 forwarding](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux#:%7E:text=disabled%20by%20default.-,Enable%20or%20disable%20IP%20forwarding,-You%20can%20use).

Second, [configure iptables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands) to permit traffic between the networks, which would look something like this:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

The iptables change isn't persistent, but the link mentions a quick way to fix that. Alternatively you could just add these lines to your bashrc or something if you prefer.

---

**Option 2**: Bridge both interfaces together

Basically this would change the setup you have now from:

eth0 --> LAN interface, 10.42.0.0/25 subnet 
    wlan0 --> WLAN interface, 10.42.1.0/25 subnet

to something like this

br0 --> LAN+WLAN interface, single subnet (can be 10.42.0.0/25 or 10.42.1.0/25)

To do this you would have to disable the DHCP server & remove the IP addresses associated with wlan0 and eth0 on the debian server, create a new bridge interface, and add them to it.
You could do that with these commands:

```
#Install bridge utils
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils

#Create the bridge & add the interfaces
sudo brctl addbr br0
sudo brctl addif br0 eth0
sudo brctl addif br0 wlan0
sudo brctl show

#Set the IP on br0 (ex. 10.42.0.1/25) and turn up the link
sudo ip addr add 10.42.0.1/25 dev br0
sudo ip link set dev br0 up
```

Then, reactivate one of your DHCP servers (whichever is handling the subnet you decided to keep) on the **br0** interface instead of what it was on before.

This would be similar to how most home Wi-Fi routers work. Keep in mind that this is bridge isn't persistent and will disappear after a reboot - you would need to create/edit the respective configuration files for netplan/network manager/whatever is handling networking on your server for it to survive a reboot. General instructions can be found [here](https://www.tecmint.com/create-network-bridge-in-ubuntu/).

Comment: Thank you @A. Trevelyan, can you check this setup please? I would like to go with Option 1, it's described in more detail there: https://serverfault.com/questions/1115223/debian-server-clients-cant-ping-between-interfaces-subnets?noredirect=1#comment1456640_1115223